# Changing iframe src with Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, src

I am trying to change an `<iframe src=... >` when someone clicks a radio button. For some reason my code is not working correctly and I am having trouble figuring out why. Here is what I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Untitled 1</title>

  <script>
  function go(loc) {
    document.getElementById('calendar').src = loc;
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe id="calendar" src="about:blank" width="1000" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

  <form method="post">
    <input name="calendarSelection" type="radio" onselect="go('http://calendar.zoho.com/embed/9a6054c98fd2ad4047021cff76fee38773c34a35234fa42d426b9510864356a68cabcad57cbbb1a0?title=Kevin_Calendar&type=1&l=en&tz=America/Los_Angeles&sh=[0,0]&v=1')" />Day
    <input name="calendarSelection" type="radio" onselect="go('http://calendar.zoho.com/embed/9a6054c98fd2ad4047021cff76fee38773c34a35234fa42d426b9510864356a68cabcad57cbbb1a0?title=Kevin_Calendar&type=1&l=en&tz=America/Los_Angeles&sh=[0,0]&v=1')" />Week
    <input name="calendarSelection" type="radio" onselect="go('http://calendar.zoho.com/embed/9a6054c98fd2ad4047021cff76fee38773c34a35234fa42d426b9510864356a68cabcad57cbbb1a0?title=Kevin_Calendar&type=1&l=en&tz=America/Los_Angeles&sh=[0,0]&v=1')" />Month
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @mbq no, I mean it's a really bad idea in this scenario. The OP seems to be embedding code from an external service. You can't fetch that using AJAX in the first place because of cross domain security, and even if you could, having the HTML and putting it into a DIV wouldn't work, because it could contain relative references to images and style sheets and such. IFrames really are the thing to go here I think

Answer (score 151, accepted):

In this case, it's probably because you are using the wrong brackets here:

```
document.getElementById['calendar'].src = loc;
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('calendar').src = loc;
```

Comment: @shinjuo `onselect` is not the correct attribute to use here. You may want to use `onclick` - notice though that that won't fire if the user uses their keyboard

Comment: That is what it was. Thanks. The reason I chose on select is because I thought that if someone tabbed through and hit space instead of mouse click that it would still change

Comment: @shinjuo yeah, that is good idea. I think though that you'd have to use some variation of `onchange` for that.

Comment: "onclick" works for the keyboard.  There is no "onselect" event.

Comment: @Aaron there is a non-standard onselect event, but it's for selecting text. If `onclick` works for turning a radio button on / off then everything's solved, great!

Comment: It seems worth noting that `document.getElementById('calendar').attributes.src = loc;` does not work. I believe that `attributes` makes a copy of the object instead of actually setting it on the node

Answer (score 76):

Maybe this can be helpful... It's plain html - no javascript:

```html
<p>Click on link bellow to change iframe content:</p>
<a href="http://www.bing.com" target="search_iframe">Bing</a> -
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org" target="search_iframe">Wikipedia</a> -
<a href="http://google.com" target="search_iframe">Google</a> (not allowed in inframe)

<iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org" width="100%" height="100%" name="search_iframe"></iframe>
```

By the way some sites do not allow you to open them in iframe (security reasons - clickjacking)

Comment: Could please explain why "http://google.com" not allowed in inframe and any advice to make it available(must not be iframe ,but similary)? Appreciate so much.

Comment: @hikaru89 this is a late reply... You cant just "make" it available. Its not allowed in iframes on purpose, google does this for many reasons on their own accord.

Comment: that's amazing, no JS and target does the work, thank you.

Answer (score 19):

Here's the jQuery way to do it:

```
$('#calendar').attr('src', loc);
```

Answer (score 9):

The `onselect` must be `onclick`.  This will work for keyboard users.

I would also recommend adding `<label>` tags to the text of "Day", "Month", and "Year" to make them easier to click on.  Example code:

```
<input id="day" name="calendarSelection" type="radio" onclick="go('http://calendar.zoho.com/embed/9a6054c98fd2ad4047021cff76fee38773c34a35234fa42d426b9510864356a68cabcad57cbbb1a0?title=Kevin_Calendar&type=1&l=en&tz=America/Los_Angeles&sh=[0,0]&v=1')"/><label for="day">Day</label>
```

I would also recommend removing the spaces between the attribute `onclick` and the value, although it can be parsed by browsers:

```
<input name="calendarSelection" type="radio" onclick = "go('http://calendar.zoho.com/embed/9a6054c98fd2ad4047021cff76fee38773c34a35234fa42d426b9510864356a68cabcad57cbbb1a0?title=Kevin_Calendar&type=1&l=en&tz=America/Los_Angeles&sh=[0,0]&v=1')"/>Day
```

Should be:

```
<input name="calendarSelection" type="radio" onclick="go('http://calendar.zoho.com/embed/9a6054c98fd2ad4047021cff76fee38773c34a35234fa42d426b9510864356a68cabcad57cbbb1a0?title=Kevin_Calendar&type=1&l=en&tz=America/Los_Angeles&sh=[0,0]&v=1')"/>Day
```

Comment: @nalply - I don't understand your downvote.  The root problem is not the spaces, which I said *should* be changed. The problem is the onselect should be onclick.  Also note that the other answer by Pekka doesn't solve the problem.  I'll re-order my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: I removed the downvote because your new edit is clearer than before.

Answer (score 8):

This should also work, although the **`src`** will remain intact:

```
document.getElementById("myIFrame").contentWindow.document.location.href="http://myLink.com";
```

Comment: This won't work when the page in the iframe is on a different domain.

Comment: How to change iframe src with Javascript function?

HTML:

 <iframe id="mainframe" width="300" height="300"></iframe>

JS:

document.getElementById("mainframe").src=url;

Answer (score 3):

Here is my updated code. It works fine and it can help you.

```
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Untitled 1</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function go(loc) {
    document.getElementById('calendar').src = loc;
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe id="calendar" src="about:blank" width="1000" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

  <form method="post">
    <input name="calendarSelection" type="radio" onclick="go('http://calendar.zoho.com/embed/9a6054c98fd2ad4047021cff76fee38773c34a35234fa42d426b9510864356a68cabcad57cbbb1a0?title=Kevin_Calendar&type=1&l=en&tz=America/Los_Angeles&sh=[0,0]&v=1')" />Day
    <input name="calendarSelection" type="radio" onclick="go('http://calendar.zoho.com/embed/9a6054c98fd2ad4047021cff76fee38773c34a35234fa42d426b9510864356a68cabcad57cbbb1a0?title=Kevin_Calendar&type=1&l=en&tz=America/Los_Angeles&sh=[0,0]&v=1')" />Week
    <input name="calendarSelection" type="radio" onclick="go('http://calendar.zoho.com/embed/9a6054c98fd2ad4047021cff76fee38773c34a35234fa42d426b9510864356a68cabcad57cbbb1a0?title=Kevin_Calendar&type=1&l=en&tz=America/Los_Angeles&sh=[0,0]&v=1')" />Month
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers worked for me, the iframe wasn't refreshing after changing the `src` so this is what finally did:

```
let calendar = document.getElementById("calendar");
calendar.setAttribute("src", srcstring);
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Answer (score 0):

change `onselect` to `onchange` in inputs and use

```
calendar.src = loc
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Untitled 1</title>

  <script>
  function go(loc) {
    calendar.src = loc;
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe id="calendar" src="about:blank" width="1000" height="450" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

  <form method="post">
    <input name="calendarSelection" type="radio" onchange="go('https://calendar.zoho.com/embed/9a6054c98fd2ad4047021cff76fee38773c34a35234fa42d426b9510864356a68cabcad57cbbb1a0?title=Kevin_Calendar&type=1&l=en&tz=America/Los_Angeles&sh=[0,0]&v=1')" />Day
    <input name="calendarSelection" type="radio" onchange="go('https://calendar.zoho.com/embed/9a6054c98fd2ad4047021cff76fee38773c34a35234fa42d426b9510864356a68cabcad57cbbb1a0?title=Kevin_Calendar&type=1&l=en&tz=America/Los_Angeles&sh=[0,0]&v=1')" />Week
    <input name="calendarSelection" type="radio" onchange="go('https://calendar.zoho.com/embed/9a6054c98fd2ad4047021cff76fee38773c34a35234fa42d426b9510864356a68cabcad57cbbb1a0?title=Kevin_Calendar&type=1&l=en&tz=America/Los_Angeles&sh=[0,0]&v=1')" />Month
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How to change iframe src with Javascript function?

HTML:

```
<iframe id="mainframe" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("mainframe").src=url;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can solve it by making the iframe in javascript

```js
  document.write(" <iframe  id='frame' name='frame' src='" + srcstring + "' width='600'  height='315'   allowfullscreen></iframe>");
```