# Change src of iframe from a popup window

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

In my web application, the user can open a popup window to select an edit an object. When the user presses OK on the popup, it's supposed to update the `src` of an iframe in the parent window (and of course reload the iframe) according to which object was selected.

My function (in the parent window) is:

```
function dismissEditPopup(win, newId) {
    newId = html_unescape(newId);
    var elem_iframe = document.getElementById("iframe_id");

    // (*) this line doesn't work
    elem_iframe.src = '/view_object/' + newId;

    elem_iframe.contentWindow.location.reload();

    win.close();
}
```

This function is called from a popup window, which contains a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    opener.dismissEditPopup(window, "hash_of_new_object");
</script>
```

The problem is that the line `(*)` fails silently. In the inspector in both Firefox 3.6 and Google Chromium, I see that the `src` attribute of the iframe *is* being updated, but `elem_iframe.contentWindow.location.href` is unchanged. (If I add a line `elem_iframe.contentWindow.location.href = elem_iframe.src;`, the assignment is ignored.). There are no errors in the Javascript error console. Strangely, it *does* work as expected if I assign to `elem_iframe.src` from the Javascript console.

I am able to change the value of a hidden `<input>` field in the same way, using `document.getElementById("hidden_id").value = newId;`.

Everything is served from the same website.

(Similar to [Changing iframe src with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript), but the answers to that question don't work, presumably because the code is called from a popup.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this line out:

```
elem_iframe.contentWindow.location.reload();
```

It's reloading the iframe and the new src is not loaded.

Comment: This seems to fix the problem, but do you know why it works? Is `.reload()` supposed to restore the original (i.e. from the HTML source) attributes of the iframe?

Comment: @Mechanical snail It's probably some kind of a race condition, where the `src` is being changed, but the `reload()` happens before the navigation takes effect - therefore it stays on the same page.