# How to determine which radio button is selected

Tags: html, iframe, radio-button

I have a program where im displaying a map in an  tag. So far i have have two radio buttons set up but im not sure how the syntax would look to determine which one is selected. If i set the value to the link i want to go to what would the  look like?

Anything along the lines of this?

`<iframe src=radiobutton1.isChecked width="1200" height="750"></iframe>`

Comment: you will need to use javascript for that

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript

Comment: I looked at that post but it does not seem to work for me, im using the frame in tab so i dont know if that could be the problem? Although i did create the script for the go() function to try, nothing comes up in the tab once i click a radio button