# Getting a variable from form entry to add to a link?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to obtain an `input class=input type=text` to add to a link not related to the page's address. The resulting `link+text-entry` will be displayed in an iframe.

I tried the following (which I found on here):

```
function GET_IT() {
    var link = document.getElementById("LINKHERE");
    var hrefOrig = link.href;
    var dd = document.getElementById("TEXT_ID");
    dd.onchange = function(){ link.href = hrefOrig + dd.value; }
}
window.attachEvent("load", init, false);
```

with:

```
<form target="IFRAME" method="get">
    <input class"input" type="text" size="25" id="TEXT_ID">
    <input type="submit" value "Go" onClick="javascript: function('GET_IT');">
</form>
```

All it did was loop back the page that everything was entered into, in the iFrame...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript function should look something like this:

```
function GET_IT() {
    var link = document.getElementById("LINKHERE");
    var hrefOrig = link.href;
    var dd = document.getElementById("TEXT_ID");

    //Change the source of the iFrame with the new HREF...
    document.getElementById('IFRAME ID').src = hrefOrig + dd.value;
}
```

This is the best answer I can give you without seeing more code.  Check out this link for a more complete example that might help you:

[Changing iframe src with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript)

Fiddler Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/VkSRY/1/

Comment: I'm not having a problem with the iframe, it's that i can't attach the entry in the text field to the end of the specified link. whenever this is attempted it just displays the original page in the iframe instead.

Comment: Is there a way to add it to the "action" ? like...

    <form target="IFRAME" action="THELINK" method="GET">
    <input class"input" type="text" size="25" id="vin">
    <input type="submit" value "Go" onClick="javascript:function('GET_IT');">

Comment: Are you able to debug through your javascript (With Chrome Debugger or Firebug) and see what is being returned?

Comment: It's rough and should be rewritten to be clearer and catch any errors, but if should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Sweet the example on fiddle.net worked great. Thanks! One question. It pops a confirmation box (white box with the link and variable together, and an OK button) anyway to prevent that and just have it do it's thing?

Comment: Yes, just remove the "alert(newSrc)"