# 2 button's open in same iframe with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want my two button's to open in the same iframe. So when button 1 was active I need button 2 to empty the frame and than load his link in there. Is this possible? This my code (so far):

```
<body>

<input type="button" id="knopSql1" type="submit" value="1e Klasse"></input>

<script>

document.getElementById('knopSql1').onclick = function() {
var iframe = frames[0] || document.createElement('iframe');

iframe.src='http://www.example.com/sql.php';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};

</script>

<input type="button" id="knopSql2" type="submit" value="2e Klasse"></input>

<script>

document.getElementById('knopSql2').onclick = function() {
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

iframe.src='http://www.example.com/sql2.php';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Try creating an iframe and then just updating the src property for it- [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript](like this example)

Comment: That's it? I feel so stupid now XD I've read that piece hundreds of times.. I just didn't get it.. Thanks @PokeItWithAStick

Comment: @PokeItWithAStick Nice website btw :)