# How to display a URL from a form box using HTML and a javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

Trying to use a form box with HTML to create a url that can be used to change an IFRAME. This is what I currently have.

```
<input type="url" id="URL" value="">
<button onclick="webFunct()">Go!</button>
<br><a href= id="ViewURL" target="WebViewer></p>

<script>
function webFunct() {
    var x = document.getElementById("URL").value;
    document.getElementById("ViewURL").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

<iframe width="100%" height="640px" name="WebViewer">
</iframe>
```

I like the form box to change the IFRAME to the website that was entered by the user to visit. I know this information is minimal and possibly *vague* but I normally don't ask for help and I don't know what else to ask.

Original code from: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_url_get

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set URL of `iframe` programmatically:

```
document.getElementById('web-view').src = url;
```

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/andunai/d1zavddu/

However, please note that many websites, e.g. `google.com` and `yahoo.com` do not permit getting themselves inserted into `iframe`s.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="url" id="URL" value="">
<button onclick="webFunct()">Go!</button>

<script>
function webFunct() {

    document.getElementById("frame").src = x;
}
</script>

<iframe width="100%" id="frame" height="640px" name="WebViewer">
</iframe>
```

Dont forget to change "x" to an url

Comment: *"The usage of inline event handling by advocation ... is heavily discouraged, instead use event listeners"*