# Changing iframe source within div tags, javascript function not executing properly

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to execute a javascript function that would change the source code for each iframe. It works if the iframe is not within any other tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
<iframe src="https://www.espn.com"  frameborder="1"  width="500" height="320"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.nbc.com"  frameborder="1"  width="500" height="320"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.cnn.com"  frameborder="1" width="500" height="320"></iframe>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
  function myFunction(){
  alert("Hello!");
  var frames = window.frames;
  for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++){
    frames[i].location = "http://www.w3schools.com";
    }  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How ever if I put the iframe within div tags the javascript for some reason doesn't reach them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <form align = "center">
      <br>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
      <br>
    </form>
<div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-6">
    <h3 id = "ESPN">ESPN</h3>
       <iframe src="https://www.espn.com"  frameborder="1"  width="500" height="320"></iframe>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-6">
    <h3 id = "NBC">NBC</h3>
      <iframe src="https://www.nbc.com"  frameborder="1"  width="500" height="320"></iframe>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-6">
    <h3 id = "CNN">CNN</h3>
      <iframe src="https://www.cnn.com"  frameborder="1" width="500" height="320"></iframe>
      <br>
</div>
</div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
  function myFunction(){
  alert("Hello!");
  var frames = window.frames;
  for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++){
    frames[i].location = "http://www.w3schools.com";
    }  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something else I need to do in order for my function to read the iframes?

Comment: Well, all your code is in `myFunction` but you never call it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing iframe src with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question, but different problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to run this

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <form align = "center" action="javascript:void(0);">
      <br>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
      <br>
    </form>
<div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-6">
    <h3 id = "ESPN">ESPN</h3>
       <iframe src="https://www.espn.com"  frameborder="1"  width="500" height="320"></iframe>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-6">
    <h3 id = "NBC">NBC</h3>
      <iframe src="https://www.nbc.com"  frameborder="1"  width="500" height="320"></iframe>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-6">
    <h3 id = "CNN">CNN</h3>
      <iframe src="https://www.cnn.com"  frameborder="1" width="500" height="320"></iframe>
      <br>
</div>
</div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript">
  function myFunction(){
  var frames = window.frames;
  for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++){
    frames[i].location = "http://www.w3schools.com";
    }  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that your iframes are in a div, but that your button is in a form.
Pressing the button submits the form (after the JavaScript function is executed) and as the form action is empty, you return to the original page. So even if your JavaScript works and the new locations of the iframes are loaded, you never get to see them, because the browser reloads the complete page, and returns to the original page with the original iframe sources.

As a first fix try to `return false` in the onclick handler; something like

```
 <button onclick="return myFunction()">Search</button>
```

and

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  function myFunction(){
    var frames = window.frames;
    alert("Hello!");
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++){
      frames[i].location = "http://www.w3schools.com/404";
    }
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

As you are already  loading jQuery, you might want to leverage this to prevent form submit (and aoind inline `onclick` handlers) by doing something like

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#search").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // this uses the event object to prevent form submit
        var frames = window.frames;
        for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++){
          frames[i].location = "http://www.w3schools.com/404";
        }
      });
   });
</script>
```

and then replace the button with

```
<button id="search">Search</button>
```