# Can I set the "src" of an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've got an HTML file that embeds a Youtube video using an iFrame. However before the video starts loading, I need to pass it an URL, since the iFrame just acts as a container.

Is it possible to do it with Javascript?.

Comment: Yes it is, set the `src` attribute.

Comment: Just like that?, but how can I tell JavaScript to load the video only when I set the attribute and not at the very beginning?.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3730175/4790490) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example if it's meeting your requirements

```
<iframe id="custom-frame" src="/test.html"></iframe>
<p>Click the button to change the value of the src attribute in the iframe </p>
<button onclick="changeFrame()">Try it</button>
<script>
      function changeFrame() {
        document.getElementById("custom-frame").src = "http://www.facebook.com";
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok. So if I don't initially set a "src" for the iFrame that means it will do nothing until I set it myself right?.

Comment: Yup, it won't do anything.