# Get ID from text field and add it to path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use Roxy Fileman to manage images and files in my CMS. The filemanager has a custom option to insert files from a text field with a button. When the button is clicked the filemanager open. This option is based on the text field ID. My problem is that I have multiple text fields so I have made the ID:s unique. But how can I add these ID to txtFieldId in the path?

This is the first text field with ID 1

```
<input type="text" name="img" id="txtSelectedFile1" class="textfield" >
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="openCustomRoxy2()" type="button">Select image</button>
```

The second one with ID 2

```
<input type="text" name="document" id="txtSelectedFile2" class="textfield" >
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="openCustomRoxy2()" type="button">Select image</button>
```

Here's the div with the iframe that opens the filemanager when the button is clicked. This is where I need to add the ID:s to the txtFieldId.

```
<div id="roxyCustomPanel2" style="display: none;">
<iframe src="/fileman/index.html?integration=custom&type=files&txtFieldId=txtSelectedFile" style="width:100%;height:100%" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

So i finally manage to solved it with help from thedarkone. The different from the answer in the link is that I left the ID in the text field unchanged and added the src function to the button.

```
<script>
function go(pth) {
  document.getElementById('roxy').src = pth;
}
</script>

<div id="roxyCustomPanel2" style="display: none;">
  <iframe id="roxy" src="about:blank" style="width:100%;height:100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<input type="text" name="img" id="txtSelectedFile1" class="textfield">
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="openCustomRoxy2(); go('/fileman/index.html?integration=custom&type=files&txtFieldId=txtSelectedFile1');" type="button">Select image</button>

<input type="text" name="document" id="txtSelectedFile2" class="textfield">
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="openCustomRoxy2(); go('/fileman/index.html?integration=custom&type=files&txtFieldId=txtSelectedFile2');" type="button">Select image</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I could get from your use case, would probably be best solved by this answer. It has both a JS solution and an pure html solution. I would prefer JS as you wouldn't have to write the whole src in each, and you are already doing that, seeing that your are using functions.

[Changing iframe src with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript)

Comment: The idea seems good but when I try it the iframe opens but doesn't load the editor. So i beleive the src doesn't get loaded to the function. Will the onselect (I even tried the onclick) work on the text field even if I click the button?

Comment: Well your solution seems good, however it can be optimized a little, but that's if this is about more than a trial thing.