# Dynamically loading iframes when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am creating a webpage where I have to load iframes inside a div.

```
<div class="sketchfab">
    <iframe class="myframe" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

And below it I have links that should provide the **source** for iframe.

```
<div class="container">
    <a href=#>A</a>
    <a href=#>B</a>
    <a href=#>C</a>
    <a href=#>D</a>
    And so on till Z
</div>
```

How can I do it?
The iframes display 3D animations of the sign gestures. So basically when I press hyperlink of A, the gesture of A appears... and so on..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing iframe src with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript)

Comment: Have you tried using `name` for the iframe and `target` on the links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="">
    <a href="#" data-url="hMxGhHNOkCU">A</a>
    <a href="#" data-url="BWXggB-T1jQ">B</a>
    <a href="#" data-url="gqOEoUR5RHg">C</a>
    <a href="#" data-url="5GcQtLDGXy8">D</a>
    And so on till Z
</div>
```

And Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
    var _this = $(this),
            iframe = $('iframe');

    iframe.attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + _this.attr('data-url'));
  });
});
```

You can check [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9n97mmdm/).