# How to change src function in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need your help with a simple code allowing me to setup a HTML5 page
where I have `iframe` tag with a `src` address target that will change everyday depending on the day of the date.
For example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.mypage.com/**day**.html"></iframe>
```

Where `day` changes everyday.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use simple `javascript` to set src `document.getElementById("iframe").setAtrribute("src","new src")`

Comment: `src` is (also) a property. One does not require `setAttribute()` for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing iframe src with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to change the src attribute of an iframe.

```js
var daily_iframe = document.getElementById('daily-iframe');
daily_iframe.src = "https://www.youtube.com";
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com" id="daily-iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: thank you
I coold not get what i'm looking for
any othe piece of code to help,
the var part is the part of src code of the address
https://www.mypage.com/day.html
is day that change everyday. 01, 02, 03, depending of the day of the today date.
any help please