# How can I make the <iframe> tag react to a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to make the iframe tag react to a variable. How?

Take a look at this one:

```
<iframe
  width="500"
  height="500"
  src=website
></iframe>

<script>
  var website = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
</script>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src=website;

Comment: Is it 'Element' or 'Elements'?

Comment: It's elements and it works. I tested it. Another way is by just assigning an id to the iframe and setting it.  Like here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript

Comment: it worked!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Solution Here !!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function iframeDidLoad() {
  var website = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
 document.getElementById('myIframe').src =website ;
}
</script>

<iframe
  width="500"
  height="500"
 onLoad="iframeDidLoad();"
  src=""
></iframe>
```

Comment: hehe that was my scratch.mit.edu account name. also, I did have to make some 'minor edits' for it to work. once it was done, it looked like it was flashing forever! a solution for that? (don't reply, reply functions, I guess, don't have the "code" thingy)

Answer (score 1):

A safer approach is to delegate the action of changing the iframe's `src` to a click of a button, for example, then you'll avoid the multiple refreshes.

You can run this example right on this very page:

```js
document.querySelector('#changeButton').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('#iframex').src = document.querySelector('#textBox').value
}
```

```css
#textBox { width: 75% }
#changeButton { width: 20% }
iframe { width: 95% }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textBox" value="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" />
<button type="button" id="changeButton">change iframe source</button>
<iframe src="" id="iframex"></iframe>
```