# getelementbyid to load pages in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

does anyone know how to make a button in HTML load another HTML page inside of an iframe?

I don't understand online tutorials for this, and here's what I tried :

```
    <div class="flex-container"> <!-- la sidebar et le iframe seront dedans -->
       
        <div class="sidebar">
            <button style="margin-top: 100px;" onclick="Function1">Thés</button>

            <button>Tisanes</button> 

            <button>Théières</button>
        </div>
        
<!--FUNCTION1-->

<script>
    function Function1() {
      document.getElementById(src="accueil.html").innerHTML = src="Thés.html" TARGET="iframe";
    }
</script>
        
        <iframe src="accueil.html" frameborder="0" style="border: none; width: inherit; height: 710px; id="iframe">
        </iframe>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Is this even how it's supposed to be done? Cause nothing is happening when the button Thés is clicked.
I'm quite new and I'm bad with javascript. Thanks if anyone has the patience to explain this to me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript

Comment: `onclick="Function1()"`

Comment: Why do you use js? It is HTML `<a href="Thes.html" target="here">click</a><iframe name="here"></iframe>` if you need more details remove js getElementById from title.

Comment: This other question is really advanced and I don't understand how I can translate this to my page sorry, also I added the () and still not working, I think my function is wrong

Comment: blackblue, I want a button to display Thés.html in the iframe when clicked, how do I do this without getelementbyid with an href? Thank you

Comment: @blackblue okay so it worked, the page is loading, but putting the button inside the <a href><button></a> like this basically cancelled all of the button's styling. here's what that button looks like now : https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/39/dh2x.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <div class="sidebar">
      <button style="margin-top: 100px;" onclick="Function1()">Thés</button>

      <button>Tisanes</button> 

      <button>Théières</button>
  </div>

  <iframe src="./accueil.html" frameborder="0" style="border: none; width: inherit; height: 710px;" id="iframe">
  </iframe>

  
<!--FUNCTION1-->

<script>

function Function1() {
 const iFrame = document.getElementById('iframe');
 iFrame.src = "Thes.html";
 console.log(iFrame)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Omg thank you so much you're like saving me. Now it seems so evident. It works 100%