# wordpress menu link target to _iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe, menu, target

Instead of having the link opened in a new tab I would like to the link to be opened in an iframe that's on the same page.

Example:
I have my front page with an iframe on it. If I click on the menu items i would like to have the urls loaded in the iframe.

I can't seem to find an answer for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Alter the iframe in your front page as below

Make sure the iframe contains a name attribute *(name="main-section")*

```
<iframe name="main-section" src="home.html"></iframe>
```

In your menu items make sure the target attribute redirects to main-section *(target="main-section")*. This is an important step.

Example:

```
<a href="#" target="main-section"></a>
```

I am pretty sure you can achieve the above steps in wordpress.

Comment: thanks. The problem I run in to is that I don't know how to change the _target of a menu item. The only option is "new tab".  https://i.ibb.co/kgQ2HkY/menu.jpg

Comment: I haven't worked on the latest Wordpress 3.x much but do give this a try https://www.agileana.com/blog/how-to-add-a-target-_blank-on-a-wordpress-menu-item/ It is definitely possible. In the worst case scenario you can directly edit the theme.php to add an extra attribute to the menu list. @MaartenNauw

Comment: I think I have to add code to the theme.php file to add an attribute. however I am not very experienced with coding. Hope you can help me out.