# How to hide URL on mouse over of a hyper link in PHP?

Tags: php, url, browser, hyperlink

basically, I have a streaming website with multiple servers and I want to hide that server link.
here the code

`<a id="server1" href="SERVER-URL" target="iframe-to-load" class="btn btn-server active">server 1</a>`

Does anyone know how to do that?

I have tried multiple methods like using **onclick** event like:

`<a id="server1" onclick="window.location.href="SERVER-URL" target="iframe-to-load" class="btn btn-server active">server 1</a>`

sometimes they open in a new tab instead of load in iframe

I want to hide exactly like http://asp-arka.blogspot.com/2014/08/hide-url-on-mouse-hover-of-hyper-link.html

Comment: Do you want to open it in an iframe or just a seperate window?

Comment: @KaiSteinke just in a iframe

Answer (score 1):

Browsers are under the control of their users.

You cannot give information (such as the URL you want to load) to the browser without it being visible to the user.

There are various levels of obfuscation you would apply (such as moving it from an `href` attribute to some JavaScript) but they are all trivially defeated by using the Network tab of the browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to dynamically change the content of an iframe, here is the solution:

Change the `src` Attribute of the iframe.

```html
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('stream').src='http://server1.example.com'">Server 1</a>

<iframe src="http://server2.example.com" frameborder="0" id="stream"></iframe>
```

I suggest you check out [Changing iframe src with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript) on stackoverflow.